# What are daily and weekly challenges?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

[image]

That is what it says in UPlay about it and that is all I know.

So what exactly are daily and weekly challenges and how do I see them in the game?

Comment: Just going out on a limb here, but I think it wants you to complete te current challenge to reveal the next one.

Comment: @KernelPanic There is no such thing as challenges ingame. That is why I ask. I know what a daily and weekly challenge is supposed to be, but it is somehow not in the game. Or it is so not obvious that I just don't see it. The coop missions can't be it, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete a weekly or daily challenge one has to go to [Shadownet](https://shadownet.splintercell.com/#!/home/single-player) via a normal browser. After logging in with your UPlay credentials you can click on Shadownet again in the top left drop down menu. There is a presentation of the currently available challenges.

Answer (score 1):

To those who are confused about the challenges. Goto shadownet which is the y button in the console or smi. Once there if connected to Internet, you'll see the challenges. 2 main challenges on top and a bunch of smaller ones on bottom. Ex. Weapons armor etc. Far bottom left one is the daily. It doesn't say but I was looking for it and I finally picked it. When I finished I received the u play points. I am still at a lost but that's what I did. The weekly states weekly challenge with a timer.  Obvious. I never got the u play points for that and I do the weekly challenge for a month now. Getting discouraged. Hope my experience helped.